# Extract <a> tags from a table working in Chrome dev tools, but not on scrapy shell

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to extract the titles of all the threads in the forum ([url](http://www.chalanachithram.com/discus/messages/115/115.html))

I extracted the xpath from the chrome dev tools and was able run it on console, and see the expected output.

The same xpath doesn't work in scrapy shell though. Attached here is a working demo of chrome devtools [image: Xpath Demo Working on Chrome]

Scrapy Shell output(not working as expected) [image]

Comment: It's all about `tbody` -- browsers add this tag automatically to the DOM but Scrapy doesn't add it (there is no `tbody` inside HTML source). Just remove it from your XPath

Comment: Thanks @gangabass, after removing `tbody` it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @gangabass, after removing `tbody` it worked like a charm. this my xpath expression for the scrapy shell `'//html//body//font//table[4]//table/tr[3]//td[2]//a//`